# How to do parallel processing of installation using Powershell Core?

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, powershell-core

This is my script for installing Firmware on multiple devices one by one.

```bsh
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string[]]$IPset,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $NewFirmwarePath
    )

$sp=$NewFirmwarePath -split "\\"
$firmware=$sp[$sp.Length -1]

foreach ($ip in $IPset)
{  
    $uri="http://"+$ip+"/xat?filename="+$firmware

    try
    {
        Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $uri  -InFile $NewFirmwarePath
        Write-host "Device IP:" $IP "is updated successfully" 
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host  "Device IP:" $IP " is failed to update"
    }
}
```

But I want to make it to install firmware on multiple devices in parallel. Looks like Powershell Core is not supporting workflow (`foreach -parallel`) . So I tried with jobs, but Jobs failed at accessing the same source file to install at multiple devices.

Please help me how can I make it work in parallel.

Comment: Please show your code using jobs and describe how it fails, including error messages.  Also, instead of `$sp=$NewFirmwarePath -split "\"; $firmware=$sp[$sp.Length -1]` you can do simply `$firmware = Split-Path -Path $NewFirmwarePath -Parent`.

Comment: You can do `invoke-command comp1,comp2,comp3 { install }` but the file has to be there.

Comment: @js2010 It appears that the install is done by pushing a firmware file to the device via HTTP, not by executing a command on the device itself.

Comment: Thanks BACON  and js2010 for the reply. yes , it installs firmware by pushing the tar file . The above scripts works fine.  I wanted to run it in parallel , I tried using workflow is not supported in core powershell , I tried using start-jobs  just before the invoke cmd , it  does successfully for 1 device, failed for other devices.  Lets say if I pass ip set of 10 device ip , it failed for rest because they are all trying to access same tar firmware file.

Comment: + WorkFlow Update
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Workflow is not supported in PowerShell Core.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WorkflowNotSupportedInPowerShellCore

Comment: PS C:\myData\Preb\FWupdateMultiple> .\FWupdateMany.ps1 -IPset 190.34.3.4,190.45.23.23  -NewFirmwarePath "C:\myData\Preb\FWupdateMultiple\20191206172905.tar"
Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Error : The process cannot access the file
'C:\myData\Preb\FWupdateMultiple\2019120617290.tar' because it is being used by another process.
At test:25 char:25

Comment: What version of PowerShell Core are you using?  Apparently it used to be [an issue with `Invoke-RestMethod -InFile` that it would lock the input file](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7669), but it was fixed over a year ago.

Comment: What is the job code?  For example, local variables aren't available in jobs with the using: scope or using a param ()

Comment: Powershell core version is :                                                                           Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      6.2.4
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    6.2.4
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.17763
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0